# is there way to use docker php in sublime plugin for syntax check

Tags: docker, sublimetext3

Post upgrading to monterey on my mac, i am not able to use sublime php syntax validation plugin. Since I am using docker for all my development, i don't want to install brew and php on my device. Is there a way I can give docker path in sublime?